# How to force AVG to include zeros

Tags: sql, null, average, zero, cross-join

I am averaging values from a column in a sub query that includes zeros. The average seems to be ignoring zero values and giving me an inflated value.

I pulled the sub query alone and I see zeros in column F (UWDays), the one I am trying to average. I tried the same query but replaced avg(mm.UWdays) with avg(NULLIF(mm.days,0)) and again I got the same values as the original pull.

```
SELECT mm.month, mm.FlagA, mm.FlagB, mm.FlagC, avg(mm.UWdays) AS UWDays,

FROM (
  select date_trunc('Month', dates_table.month) as month, 
customer_table.customer_id,

Case WHEN (table1.attribute1 LIKE '%Yes%' AND table2.attribute2 LIKE '%Yes%' and table3.attribute3 NOT LIKE '%Yes%') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS FlagA, 
Case WHEN (table1.attribute1 LIKE '%Yes%' AND table2.attribute2 LIKE '%Yes%' AND table3.attribute3 LIKE '%Yes%') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS FlagB, 
Case WHEN (table1.attribute1 LIKE '%Yes%' AND table2.attribute2 LIKE '%No%' AND table3.attribute3 LIKE '%Yes%') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS FlagC, 


CASE WHEN (min(table1.date) is null AND max(table1.date) is null) THEN 0 ELSE count(table1.date) end AS UWDays


FROM customer_table cross dates_table  
left outer join table1 ON customer_table.customer_id= table1.customer_id
left outer join table2 on customer_table.customer_id= table2.customer_id
left outer join table3 on customer_table.customer_id= table3.customer_id

group by 1,2,3,4,5
order by 2,1) mm
GROUP BY  1,2,3,4
```

Answer (score 1):

`AVG()` does *not* exclude zeroes.  However, it does ignore `NULL` values, so perhaps that is what you mean -- particularly because your query has `LEFT JOIN`s which would tend to generate `NULL` values.

You can treat `NULL` values as `0` using `COALESCE()`:

```
avg(coalesce(mm.UWdays), 0)
```